# merge unsorted file to sorted file using shell command

Tags: text-processing, merge, join

I want to merge/join or produce a new merged file . Both files contain common IDs in the first column .

File 1 looks like this

```
ID
Tb927.4.4670
Tb927.8.3630
Tb09.160.4310
Tb927.8.3650
```

File 2 contains the ID and also functions for each gene and looks like this

```
ID              Function 1    Other field
Tb09.211.0140     A               eg
Tb11.03.0080      B               eg
Tb927.8.6200      C               eg
Tb927.7.690       D               eg
```

However, some IDs are missing in my file 2 as not all genes have known function so the fields in my file 2 are less than in my file 1. The IDs in file 2 are also sorted differently from my file 1.

I want my merged file to follow the sequence in my file 1 with merged functions in the output . For the missing ID, it can either be empty or something like return '-' .

Is it possible to merge this kind of files using linux command?

Answer (score 2):

using `awk`

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$1]=$0; next};
     ($1 in a){print a[$1]; next};
      {print $1, "-", "-"}' file2 file1
```

Or slightly terser

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$1]=$0; next};
  {print $1 in a?a[$1]:$1FS"-"FS"-"}' file2 file1
```

Comment: somehow that didn't work for me. i've got something like this : ID
 - -
Tb927.4.4670
 - -
Tb927.8.3630
 - -
Tb09.160.4310
 - -
Tb927.8.3650
 - -
Tb927.8.3560
 - -
Tb927.8.3620
 - -
Tb927.6.4970
 - -
Tb927.1.2110
 - -
Tb927.2.3030
 - -
Tb09.160.2280
 - -
Tb927.7.2180
 - -
Tb11.01.1300

Comment: @user3072782, what character are your fields delimited by?

Comment: tab-delimited .

Comment: @user3072782, works like a charm with tab-delimited files at this end

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sort(1)` on your lot of files, the program is smart enough to just merge if the files are already sorted.